# missing dependency for FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to install FFMPEG on a virtual dedicated server with Red Hat Fedora Core 7 but get the following error:

```
Error: Missing Dependency: libvorbisenc.so.0 is needed by package ffmpeg
```

I've tried installing libvorbisenc.so.0, but it says "no package available".

When I try to install the latest version, libvorbisenc.so.2, it says it's already installed.

This is the final issue after several, the first being that I was unable to install ffmpeg using:

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

so I had to create the following file, /etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo:

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpcheck=1
enabled=1
```

but that couldn't find the repomd.xml file, so I had to change it to:

```
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/7.3/en/i386/dag
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add rpmfusion to your repository. Rpmfusion can be added with the following command:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm'
```

Comment: Well... Livna should contain ffmpeg, so it should be working. I'd guess the problem has more to do with the Repos. 

First off Redhat 7.3 has nothing to do with Fedora Core 7, which may be causing some confusion. When you look in yum.repos.d, you should see something like fedora.repo, and livna.repo. If those are there, try doing a "yum list all | grep -i ffmpeg", and see if anything shows up.

Good luck getting everything configured!

Comment: Thanks again Bear! It turned out I needed the asterisk after the ffmpeg b/c my package was called ffmpeg.i386.  Silly!

Answer (score 0):

RPMFusion doesn't support Fedora 7 anymore, but I was able to find a mirror w/the correct version after a ton of searching.

I also had a really old version of livna already installed, so I had to upgrade rather than install.

For anyone interested, here's the command:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rpm.livna.org/fedora/7/i386/livna-release-7-2.noarch.rpm'
```

Also, this version of rpmfusion uses a different name for ffmpeg so I had to change my yum command to:

```
yum install ffmpeg*
```

Thanks again for your help!!